# How to use to Google Dictionary as an API?

Tags: java, dictionary, google-api

Because the Google Dictionary API is deprecated (e.g., following)

```
http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=love
```

and has been replaced with define (e.g., following)

```
https://www.google.com/#q=define+love
```

Does anybody know how to use/invoke the "Google define" API in java?

Here is the chrome extension which does similar thing.

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-dictionary-by-goog/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja
```

As an alternative, are there any open source dictionary APIs? I found Oxford (OED), Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, Wordnik APIs which provide APIs in subscription models.

Also found Wordnet 3.1 which is pretty old. Not sure if it being updated or not.

Answer (score 65):

Unfortunately, like others have said, the Google Dictionary API is deprecated.

As I needed a Google Dictionary API for my project, I decided to create one.

I scraped the web page for the URL `https://www.google.com/#q=define+term` where `term` is any word you want to get meaning of, and created the API. You can find it [here](https://dictionaryapi.dev/).

## How to use

The basic syntax of a URL request to the API is shown below:

https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/<--language_code-->/<--word-->

As an example, to get definition of English word hello, you can send request to:

https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/hello

The API also provides other meanings of the word, example sentences, and synonyms, if any.

If you want me to include any other details, please comment and I will happily extend the API to cover your needs.

The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/meetDeveloper/googleDictionayApi).

Comment: In case anyone is interested - [this answer is discussed in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170899/towc-can-someone-change-the-title-so-it-doesnt-involve-my-name).

Comment: This is awesome, please keep it up

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar Thanks, I am adding new features, please suggest some if you want, I will be more than happy to include them.

Comment: Hi @SurajJain, it’s actually written quite clean and concise . It includes everything I want. But I’d like to get the word pronunciation(phonetic). And you might want to order the definitions as an array. Or we’d have to loop through word classes to find what we need.. for example ({“0”: {data}... thank you

Comment: Isn't it already an array of objects?? Suppose it is noun and has 4 definition, then the definition is like [{ }, { }, { }, { }] .

Comment: You can access it like suppose returned json is stored in variable definition. Then you can access meaning as follow, meaning.noun[0], meaning.noun[1] .. and so on. @RawandAhmedShaswar

Comment: What about the pronunciation field? It is important right?

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar I will add it by tomorrow, will also add the sound. Could you open all the feature request on this API github page/

Comment: Yeah. Sure.. waiting for your action on tomorrow’s update

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar Hey, did your purpose was solved??

Comment: Does this still work? On the linked site whatever word I enter I get error stating it couldn't find any results...

Comment: @KoviNET It works, I just tried.

Comment: I've created npm package for this library, if anyone require please visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-dictionary-api

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a true Google API version as if you search a Verb on Google Search, it also lists its forms in different tenses but this API only lists details and examples and exclude many of other information

Comment: @helloworld API does not provide everything that google search provides, I am slowly adding all the things.

Comment: @SurajJain I wasn't referring to your library :) google-dictionary-api  doesn't provide those details (verb form for  past-present-future tense). However, you do get them when you do a normal google search.

Answer (score 9):

Yes! Google Dictionary access is removed. 
[This](http://google-dictionary.so8848.com/) does the same job but still has access.

AFAIK, [Dictionary Lookup](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/) is one of the most popular as listed by

www.programmableweb.com/apitag/dictionary/1?q=dictionary&sort=mashups

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will look into it.

Comment: In an attempt to improve this answer: This is the 'Dictionary Lookup' (aonaware.com) API service index page - http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx. The API for querying a specific word through all affiliated dictionaries can be inspected in this page: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?op=Define. Also, a specific dictionary can be specified, here: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?op=DefineInDict (the list of dictionaries is available here: http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx/DictionaryList).

Answer (score 0):

To get the very best definitions I would go with api for Merriam-Webster or Oxford.  As long as your use is not commercial you'll be okay up to 1,000 queries per day (Merriam-Webster) and up to 3,000 queries per month (Oxford).

Comment: It seems [Oxford API allows commercial use](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/api-terms-and-conditions).