# How to distinguish english sentence syntax in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-crawler

Im looking for an efficient way to distinguish the syntax of english grammar (verb, noun, adjective etc) using a python program.

Currently my method of achieving this is by having the program read through the source code of dicionary.com and find the info using some cutting

```
url = "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + x + "?s=t"]
request = urllib2.Request(url)
handle = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = handle.read()

# cut the html code to the correct spot
splitted_page = content.split(b"<span class=\"dbox-pg\">", 1)
splitted_page = splitted_page[1].split(b"</span>", 1)
word_type.append(splitted_page)
```

where x is the word that i am searching for. My problem is this is proving to be very difficult as the source code for this website is not consistance so this code works for some words but not the others.

Im wondering if there is a more foolproof way of doing this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A challenge, parsing English is. An offline word list such as ASpell, you should use.

Comment: https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 separate issues? 1. scrape the web page consistently and 2. process English words? For 2 you can use a library like http://www.nltk.org/. For the 1st I don't think looking for a specific node is the way to go, though I'm not certain I follow what specific data you are trying to get from dictionary.com.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740789/how-to-use-to-google-dictionary-as-an-api has some dictionary APIs you can look at.  Another problem with your question is that words can have more than one grammar use.  e.g. act is both a noun and a verb

Comment: Maybe use NLTK(Natural Language Toolkit) library.

Answer (score 1):

If not using NLTK I would go for recognizing specific suffixes to see what is where.
Just a layout.

So, split a sentence to words and see which words ends with "ed", "ing", "tion", "ay" "et" "ct" "ee" "ly" "ful" "less" "ness" etc.

And short forms "n.t" ".ve" "'re" "'d"...

Support this with some light weight dictionary like CMUDict which only contains words and their respective pronounciations.

Have somewhere a list of irregular verbs and usual forms like "am" "is" "are" "was" "were" "have" "has" "will" "shall" "do" "does" "did" and their negatives.

With this system you can see whether you got an English word at all.

From its suffix and position in the sentence you can pretty well guess its role in the sentence.

Otherwise, even if you have separate lists of verbs and nouns it is usually hard to tell (only by looking at this word) whether it is noun or a verb.
So you will have to have a context manager in any case. (If you want your guesses to be 98% correct).

Search for any English dictionary (if you would not use CMUDict) and parse it for your use.

Don't do it online! It will be slow and there is big amount of other problems that may appear, including inconsistent returns and connection problems.