# grep/sed/awk paragraphs or sections from lynx output for a dictionary definition

Tags: bash, sed, grep, lynx

I have a bash function that let's me see a word definition from Google:

```
defword() {
    if [ -z $2 ]; then
        header=30
    else
        header=$2
    fi
    lynx -dump "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=define%3A+${1}&btnG=Google+Search" | grep -v "\[1\] Google" | grep -v "define: ${1}__" | grep -v "\[2\]IMAGES" | head -${header}
}
```

e.g. `defword dog` would display the first 30 lines of output for 'dog' and `defword dog 50` would display the first 50 lines.

It occurs to me that this could be cleaner output if I can just grab the 'noun', 'verb', 'wikipedia' sections etc.

Can you suggest ways (maybe with grep or sed or awk?) that I could run say `defword dog noun` that will display the whole of the noun section (from the word 'noun' down to the blank line before the next section), `defword dog noun 2` to display just definition 2 from the noun section (and same for 'verb' or 'adjective' if those sections are present), and `defword dog wikipedia` which displays the wikipedia definition that is present below noun and verb (can see that wikipedia section by doing `defword dog 100` with the above function)?

Comment: Although this doesnt answer your question directly you would be better off using an API such as https://dictionaryapi.dev/ Running `curl https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/dog` would get you a json formatted result which would be easy to parse by piping to something like `jq`

Comment: That's fascinating also, thanks for this. My question I guess is for a generic web crawl situation, so I'd still like to see how I could use grep/awk/sed for the original question, but I'm also interested in these api's: are there also other "api.dev" things like this for other subjects? And, is `jq` the only sensible way to parse json's on the console, or are there other built in tools that can do as good a job?

Comment: There will be other API's for all sorts of things - an API is what is used in general for programs to talk to web pages - many webpages have there own APIs, including google for all its services (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) . Note they can often be tricky to get going with as they'll need a key set up and have limited requests. The dictionary one above happens to be quite straightfoward.

Comment: I've always used jq if I need to do this on the command line, or python and its json package for more involved work. For the dictionary by the way the jq command would be `jq '.[] | .meanings[] | select(.partOfSpeech=="noun") | .definitions | .[].definition'`

Comment: Also it turns out the link I gave you dictionaryapi.dev does just search google and does the text processing you are looking for! Its developer presents it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48983463/1581658 It is written in javascript rather than bash

Comment: oh, sure, I know what an API is in general (I use them all the time in various programming), but I've not seen web pages like this before. I played around with the dictionary one, but oddly (since you said it just searches google) it seems to lack definitions compared to the results from Google. Thanks very much for the `jq` snippet, that's great, I'll build some samples and keep in my profile, I'll definitely make good use of these in future. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matching between two lines is possible with sed (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264977)

To match between your lines you can pipe to

```
  sed -n '/^   noun$/,${p;/^$/q}'
```

This allows your entire script to be tidied to just be

```
lynx -dump "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=define%3A+${1}&btnG=Google+Search" | sed -n '/^   '"${2:-noun}"'$/,${p;/^$/q}'
```

By also using the default parameter syntax in bash (https://coderwall.com/p/s8n9qa/default-parameter-value-in-bash)

Comment: I think you should write the sed pattern in singlequotes, and then change to double quotes for the expansion only, then you also avoid future problems like the one you originally had with `${p;/^$/q}` getting interpreted by the shell.

Comment: @andlrc good point: edited to do that